# What is the official definition of a 2-cellular region?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I read some paper about planar graphs (or projective plane graphs) and they sometimes mention the concept of 2-cell region. But they didn't explain anything. I feel it is equivalent to an open disc. So I guess there's a concept of k-cell region.

[image]

- Shibuya H, Suzuki Y. 1-Embeddability of complete multipartite graphs on the projective plane[J]. Discrete Mathematics, 2021, 344(9): 112518.

Has this concept been rigorously described in any textbook? It feels like it belongs in the category of basic topology. I need to supplement this knowledge seriously.  Rather than being satisfied with figuring out this one concept, I may be looking for antecedent knowledge of topological graph theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. An $n$-cell is homeomorphic to an $n$-disk with boundary an $(n-1)$-sphere. The language of *cells* and *cell complexes* come from algebraic topology, where they are a convenient and common way to construct all sorts of spaces (not just manifolds). Since these spaces are constructed *inductively* by attaching each $n$-cell to the $(n-1)$-skeleton (all cells of dimension less than $n$), they are naturally compatible with inductive arguments on dimension.

Specifically, I'm referring to *CW-complexes,* which have a finiteness property and weak topology, which you can read a bit more about [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/CW_complex).